# Не запускается программа при окончании загрузки системы

Tags: android, android-broadcastreceiver

У меня в приложении есть слушатель, который наследуется от класса BroadcastReceiver. После того, как система была закружена, должен вызываться метод onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) этого класса. Это все замечательно работает. Но я столкнулся с ситуацией: мое устройство на базе андроида было не корректно выключено (просто выключили питание без завершения работы ОС). Это привело к тому, что мое приложение перестало автоматически запускаться после загрузки системы. Переустановка приложения решила эту проблему. Но возникает вопрос - что могло случится с мои приложением? Как может повлиять некорректное завершение работы ОС андроид на работу таких приложений?